# Can't take value from Input Type ="select"

Tags: reactjs, forms, reactstrap

I am trying to take value from a drop down menu but isn't able to do so .
My code for the dropdrop is :

```
  <Input type="select" name="type" id="etype" value={this.state.type} onChange={this.changeTypeHandler}>
                            <option value="Doctor">Doctor</option>
                            <option value ="Nurse"> Nurse</option>
                        </Input>
```

while my  changeTypeHandler is

```
 changeTypeHandler = (event) => {
        this.setState({ type: event.target.value });
    }
```

I have seen this.state.selectedValue in on of the solution for  type . So what should be done in this case ?
Sorry If its a basic question but I am new to react and isn't able to find the solution for this .Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this :

```
<select name="type" id="etype" value={this.state.selectedValue} 
      onChange={this.changeTypeHandler}>
      <option value="Doctor">Doctor</option>
      <option value ="Nurse"> Nurse</option>
</select >
```

and for onChange function

```
changeTypeHandler =(event) =>
{
    this.setState({selectedValue:event.target.value});
}
```

Comment: Still Not taking values

Comment: Have you created the state selectedValue ?

Comment: I have replaced your selectedValue  with type..which in my state .

Comment: have you replaced it in both changeTypeHandler function and input value attribute ?

Comment: I have updated the above code to the original version . Now let me try <select> instead of <Input type = select

Comment: same issue isn't able to take only that value

Comment: Thanks I missed something I guess .  rewrote  your code and it worked . Can you tell me why we can't get that write in <Input type = select  > tag ?

Comment: @BATMAN you definitely can

Answer (score 0):

hi there you can use this instead of that

```js
function get_selected_input() {
  alert(document.querySelector('#etype').value)
}
```

```html
    <select type="select" name="type" id="etype" onChange=get_selected_input(this)>
                            <option value="">Select Option</option>
                           <option value="Doctor">Doctor</option>
                            <option value ="Nurse"> Nurse</option>
                        </select>
```

Comment: how will I set state of the component ? how to set type attribute in such case as document. is showing error

Answer (score 0):

You need to use value instead of selectedValue.

```
changeTypeHandler = (event) => {this.setState({type: event.target.value})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better todo it in the Reactjs way, which means you can use **select tag**

```
<select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="Doctor">Doctor</option>
            <option value="Nurse">Nurse</option>
</select>
```

and the handeler

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }
```

and this way of doing it is also recomanded by [**React official web site**](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import React from "react";
import { Input } from "reactstrap";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    type: ""
  };

  changeTypeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({ type: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Input
          type="select"
          name="type"
          id="etype"
          value={this.state.type}
          onChange={this.changeTypeHandler }
        >
          <option value="Doctor">Doctor</option>
          <option value="Nurse"> Nurse</option>
        </Input>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working .This was what I was doing at start

Comment: @BATMAN you need to elaborate since this is working perfectly fine in this sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-water-ww8t0

Comment: I don't know but even when I was selecting a value it was sending an empty string

Comment: only difference in your and mine code was you initialised with "" (double)  while I used ''(single )  .Does that make any difference ?

Comment: no, but since this code is working in sandbox it should in your local too. did you try sandbox?